# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception when recreating integer from pixel values

Tags: java, image-processing, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to separate the red, green and blue values in an image and do some permutation on the arrays. After doing the permutation, am trying to write the image but found an exception while writing the pixel values to an integer.

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 272

    at encryption.core.receiveFramePath(core.java:203)

    at encryption.fny.jButton3ActionPerformed(fny.java:657)

    at encryption.fny.access$900(fny.java:14)
```

The java code is:

```
    public class core {

    Random rand = new Random();

    public void receiveFramePath(String[] fpath, String key)
    {
        System.out.println("Number of frames to be processed are " + fpath.length);
        System.out.println("Key received is " + key);
        int len;

        len = key.length();
        //String part1, part2;
        String part1 = key.substring(0, 2);
        String part2 = key.substring(2, len);

        System.out.println("Message to be splitted is " + key);
        System.out.println("The parts are " + part1 + " and " + part2);

        int fC ;// this is frmaeCount
        fC = fpath.length;
        System.out.println("  No of strings to be processed are " + fC);
        BufferedImage[] img = new BufferedImage[fC];
        int i;// to run the for loop
        for( i = 0; i < fC; i++ )
        {    
                    // Code to read the image pixel values

                    File f = new File(fpath[i]);
                    try {
                                img[i] = ImageIO.read(f);
                        }
                    catch(Exception e)
                        {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    int[] RGBarray = null;
                    int c = 0;
                    int r = 0;
                    int [][] alphaPixels = null;
                    int [][] redPixels = null;
                    int [][] greenPixels = null;
                    int [][] bluePixels =null;

                    c = img[i].getWidth();
                    r = img[i].getHeight();

                    //System.out.println(" Width of the image is " + c + " The height of the image is " + r);
                    RGBarray = img[i].getRGB(0,0,c,r,null,0,c);   

                    alphaPixels = new int [r][c];
                    redPixels = new int [r][c];
                    greenPixels = new int [r][c];
                    bluePixels = new int [r][c];
                    int ii = 0;// to run inside seperating a loop

                    for(int row=0; row<r; row++)
                    {
                       for(int col=0; col<c; col++)
                       {
                      //    alphaPixels[row][col] = ((RGBarray[ii]>>24)&0xff);
                          redPixels[row][col] = ((RGBarray[ii]>>16)&0xff);
                          greenPixels[row][col] = ((RGBarray[ii]>>8)&0xff);
                          bluePixels[row][col] = (RGBarray[ii]&0xff);
                          ii++;
                       }
                    }
                    // code to read the image pixel values ends here

                    // Fisher alg starts here
                    // logic for permutation on red pixels
                    for ( int ro = 0; ro < r ; ro++)
                    {
                       int[] arr = new int[c];

                       for (int co = 0; co < c; co++)
                       {
                           arr[co] = redPixels[ro][co];
                       }

                       int max = arr.length - 1;
                       int min = 0;
                       int rnum;
                       int larr = arr.length - 1;
                       int[] parr = new int[arr.length];// to store the permuted array 
                       int flag = 0;// 'flag' to flag the recurring number
                       int plen = parr.length - 1;

                       for(int z = 0 ; z < arr.length ; z++)
                       {
                            rnum = (rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min);// roll for the random number
                            parr[plen] = arr[rnum];
                            arr[rnum] = arr[larr];

                            larr--;// to reduce the size of the original array
                            plen--;// to make the parr to act like a stack
                            max--;
                       }
                       for(int z = 0; z<arr.length;z++ )
                       {
                           redPixels[ro][z] = parr[z];
                       }
                    } 
                    // &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& redPixels permuatation ends here
                    // &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& redPixels permuatation ends here
                    // &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& redPixels permuatation ends here

                    // logic for permutation on GREEEEN pixels
                    // logic for permutation on GREEEEN pixels
                    // logic for permutation on GREEEEN pixels

                    for ( int ro = 0; ro < r ; ro++)
                    {
                       int[] arr = new int[c];

                       for (int co = 0; co < c; co++)
                       {
                           arr[co] = greenPixels[ro][co];
                       }

                       int max = arr.length - 1;
                       int min = 0;
                       int rnum;
                       int larr = arr.length - 1;
                       int[] parr = new int[arr.length];// to store the permuted array 
                       int flag = 0;// 'flag' to flag the recurring number
                       int plen = parr.length - 1;

                       for(int z = 0 ; z < arr.length ; z++)
                       {
                            rnum = (rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min);// roll for the random number
                            parr[plen] = arr[rnum];
                            arr[rnum] = arr[larr];

                            larr--;// to reduce the size of the original array
                            plen--;// to make the parr to act like a stack
                            max--;
                       }
                       for(int z = 0; z<arr.length;z++ )
                       {
                           greenPixels[ro][z] = parr[z];
                       }
                    } 
                    // &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& greenPixels permuatation ends here
                    // &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& greenPixels permuatation ends here
                    // &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& greenPixels permuatation ends here

                    for ( int ro = 0; ro < r ; ro++)
                    {
                       int[] arr = new int[c];

                       for (int co = 0; co < c; co++)
                       {
                           arr[co] = bluePixels[ro][co];
                       }

                       int max = arr.length - 1;
                       int min = 0;
                       int rnum;
                       int larr = arr.length - 1;
                       int[] parr = new int[arr.length];// to store the permuted array 
                       int flag = 0;// 'flag' to flag the recurring number
                       int plen = parr.length - 1;

                       for(int z = 0 ; z < arr.length ; z++)
                       {
                            rnum = (rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min);// roll for the random number
                            parr[plen] = arr[rnum];
                            arr[rnum] = arr[larr];

                            larr--;// to reduce the size of the original array
                            plen--;// to make the parr to act like a stack
                            max--;
                       }
                       for(int z = 0; z<arr.length;z++ )
                       {
                           bluePixels[ro][z] = parr[z];
                       }
                    }
                    // &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& bluePixels permuatation ends here
                    // &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& bluePixels permuatation ends here
                    // &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& bluePixels permuatation ends here

                    int rgba;
                    for(int row=0; row<r; row++)
                    {
                        for(int col=0; col<r; col++)
                        {
                            rgba = (alphaPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 24 | (redPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 16 | (greenPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 8 | (bluePixels[row][col] & 0xff);
                            img[i].setRGB(col, row, rgba);
                        }
                    }
                    try{
                        ImageIO.write(img[i], "png", new File("D:/Projects/Problem domains/Ashwini/encrypted/encr_"+i+".png"));
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }// for loop
    }// method ends
}// class ends
```

The exception is at line

```
 rgba = (alphaPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 24 | (redPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 16 | (greenPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 8 | (bluePixels[row][col] & 0xff);
```

What might have gone wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo:

```
for(int row=0; row<r; row++) {
    for(int col=0; col<r; col++)
                       ^
```

should be

```
for(int row=0; row<r; row++) {
    for(int col=0; col<c; col++)
```